# Cannot print api response on console

Tags: java, eclipse, rest-assured, testng-dataprovider

For some reason, when I try to print the response using print statement for the response body, the system does not print. please help.

In the following API post, I am using Java, rest-assured, TestNG on Eclipse Neon 3. Using @DataProvider annotation, I am passing multiple params in Post request to see the response of the call. Any help would be truly appreciated.

```
package com.auto.restassured;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.basic;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;


public class FilePostToVirusTotal {


static String baseURL = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report";
Response myResponse;


@DataProvider(name = "md5hashes")
public String[][] createMd5Hashes() {

    return new String[][]  {

        {"md51", "c1105fb75bc00b5e487f7b26a5be7088"},
        {"md52", "213f3287c81d09b095334c9f3151cff8"},
        {"md53", "b00c2c458b4cf1eb172e354f54f0fe12"},
        {"md54", "32ac9b6b6b7cdbfce179acc5edae98c3"},
        {"md55", "510b0b81b85c025d538ed4bad78dc64f"},

    };

}

@Test(dataProvider = "md5hashes")
public void md5JsonTest(String apikey, String resource)
{

    //Catch API response
    myResponse = given().param("text", resource).param("text", "34b937e6e2d28ee6f93a70392d958de8ac4a8dd842e08bbca9bcb0d22f9b9960").when().post(baseURL);
    //Print Response
    System.out.println(myResponse.getBody().asString());

}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't print at all, or it doesn't print what you're expecting? Is the method running? Did you confirm in a debugger?

Comment: I set the debugger on at the method and after the print statement. It does not do anything. However, the method is posting the requests but nothing printed at Response. When I manually do it using Postman, it responds back.

Comment: What is the response?  Check with myResponse.getStatus() -- this can only happen if your responsebody is empty..

Comment: Thank you very much. I did myResponse.getstatusCode(). It printed out 403, which means forbidden access to the site that I am requesting to. Since, this is form post, should I check with the apikey ? But when I am trying with Postman manually with the same apikey, I am able to get the response ! It is very surprising that I cannot get the response back. Any thoughts, please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in log methods e.g. `given().log().all()` for request and `then().log().all()` for response

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Request {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    RestAssured.baseURI="http://dummy.restapiexample.com";
    given().    
    //queryParam("key","AIzaSyDIQgAh0B4p0SdyYkyW8tlG-y0yJMfss5Y").
    body("{\"name\":\"test111\",\"salary\":\"123\",\"age\":\"23\"}").
    when().
    post("/api/v1/create").
    then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and()
    .body("status",equalTo("success")).log().body();
    System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Result:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "name": "test111",
        "salary": "123",
        "age": "23",
        "id": 65
    }
}
Done
```

Comment: use can use .log.all()  instead of log().body() --> to get all detail response

Comment: import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;